# open source code codeigniter with backendpro

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter with backendpro. it work ok on my localhost. when i upload to host, it's not work. I type my domain, it load blank page.

**-Sever:**
Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 PHP/5.2.16    mod_antiloris/0.4
MySQL client version: 5.0.51a
PHP extension: mysqli

**my local:**
Apache
MySQL client version: 5.1.37
PHP extension: mysql

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Look for your application folder inside the system folder and check that all the values there are correctly placed. It happens a lot, you might have something like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/codeigniterdemo/";
```

Which should be like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://myhost.com/";
```

Also, you should check for the remaining values or any "weird" message not being shown, try viewing the source code for the "blank" page.

Hope I can help

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a number of things to check.

1. `/system/application/config` folder

   - Change the base address to the new one in `config.php`;
   - Update your database credentials in `database.php`;
   - If you added custom routes in `routes.php`, check if they work with the new directory structure.
2. `.htaccess`

   - If you used a custom redirect, probably the RewriteBase is a subdirectory of localhost, while in your new site - if codeigniter is installed in the base http directory - it will simply be localhost. Check it.

At the moment it's all I can think of; probably you'll have to do something else though. To be sure, make `logs/` writable.